# Adaptive segue with existing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, adaptive-ui

I have a modal (form sheet) segue in my application on the iPad that changes to a `UINavigationController` when the `horizontalSizeClass` is `regular`.
To achieve that, I am using `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` as in the code below:

```
extension MyListViewController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    func presentationController(_ controller: UIPresentationController, viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle style: UIModalPresentationStyle) -> UIViewController? {
        if style == .fullScreen {
            return UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller.presentedViewController)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want my `presentedViewController` to be shown not in a new `UINavigationController`, but in the same `UINavigationController` that is already being used in my whole application. That way, I would not need to specify a Back button and could reuse the same `navigationBar` of the main `UINavigationController`.

How can I implement that?